# Not able to understand the for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

Can anyone please explain the for loop of the following code to me?

I am not able to understand the meaning of the content in the for loop.

```js
var colours = ["Red", "Yellow", "Blue"];
var text = "";
var i;
for (i = 0; i < colours.length; i++) {
  text += colours[i] + " ";
}
document.getElementById("colourList").innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<p id="colourList"></p>
```

Comment: Just getting the color from `colours` one by one using for loop and appending it into `text`.

Comment: What specifically don't you understand?  The `+=` operator?  The `+` operator?  Indexing an array?  What a `for` loop does?  Do you expect a different result from the code than what you observe?

Comment: In Short the loop is doing  `text = colours[0] + " " + colours[1] + " " + colours[2] + " ";`

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the comments i added:

```
var colours = ["Red", "Yellow", "Blue"]; // Define an array with all the color names
var text = ""; // Initialize "text" as empty string
var i; // Declare the loop variable

// For loop, start with 0(i=0), end with the length of array "colours"(i < colours.length), increase i by one after each loop iteration (i++)
for (i = 0; i < colours.length; i++) { // For each color in array colors...
    text += colours[i] + " "; // Add the name of the current color to "text", followed by a whitespace
}
// "text" now contains all colors sepearted by whirespaces
document.getElementById("colourList").innerHTML = text; // Show all the colors in the "colourList" HTML element
```

Answer (score 0):

The loop is used to iterate over the array **colors** to concatenate all the value i.e. Red, yellow, blue by space.

Answer (score 0):

```
const colours = ["Red", "Yellow", "Blue"];
let text = "";
let i;
for (i = 0; i < colours.length; i++) {
  text += colours[i] + " ";
}
document.getElementById("colourList").innerHTML = text;
```

Iterations:

```
1. text += colours[0] + " "; // text = "Red "
2. text += colours[1] + " "; // text = "Red Yellow "
3. text += colours[2] + " "; // text = "Red Yellow Blue "
```

Also I took the liberty to change var to let and const. Plese use let and const insteadof var wherever possible. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let

Comment: OP is asking to understand how the `for` loop works, not to have their code critiqued and rewritten.  How does this answer the question?

Answer (score -1):

You have an array (`colours`) containing three items (your colours).  To access each *element* in the array you use a numeric index of the item.

To access the element of the array at each index you use this code: `colours[index]`. In your example:

```
colours[0] is "Red"
colours[1] is "Yellow"
colours[2] is "Blue"
```

The `for` loop does this programmatically by starting at `0` and continuing until the total number of items in the `colours` array:

```
for (i = 0; i < colours.length; i++)
```

Before the loop is started, an empty string is stored in the variable `text`.  As the loop *iterates*, the colour that is the next element in the `colours` array is appended to `text`:

```
text += colours[i] + " ";
```

Thinking about the loop you have, this performs three iterations:

```
1. text += colours[0] + " "; // i = 0. text = "Red "
2. text += colours[1] + " "; // i = 1. text = "Red Yellow "
3. text += colours[2] + " "; // i = 2. text = "Red Yellow Blue "
```

Once `i` reaches the value of 2 it is no longer *below* the length of the array and so the loop terminates.

The following snippet shows the value of `text` at each iteration:

```js
var colours = ["Red", "Yellow", "Blue"];
var text = "";
var i;
for (i = 0; i < colours.length; i++) {
  text += colours[i] + " ";
  console.log(`i is ${i}. Text = "${text}"`);
}
console.log("Loop completed");
```